# Is it possible to find nearby cross street in New York using geocoder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, google-geocoder, rails-geocoder

How can i find cross street for a restaurant or building using geocoder like yelp?

https://www.yelp.com/biz/am%C3%A9lie-new-york?osq=Restaurants

```
22 W 8th St
New York, NY 10011,
b/t 5th Ave & Mac Dougal St ,
Greenwich Village
```

cross street like this **b/t 5th Ave & Mac Dougal St**

possible using gocoder gem ?

Thanks